# けど vs. が for "but" conjuction

Tags: word-choice, nuances, conjunctions

[This question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2738/%e3%81%a7%e3%82%82-demo-versus-%e3%81%91%e3%81%a9-kedo-to-mean-but) covers the difference between でも and けど for "but", the difference being that でも can be used at the beginning of a sentence. But けど and が are used in very much the same way, syntactically. What exactly is the difference between these two expressions?

Comment: While searching for the perfect answer I came across this. Link:- https://japanesetactics.com/how-to-say-but-in-japanese-demo-kedo-ga-and-more.
This article explains the previous question too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
今日はサッカーをして疲れたけど楽しかった。
今日はサッカーをして疲れたが楽しかった。
```

```
去年は遊びまくった。けど、成績は落ちなかった。
去年は遊びまくった。が、成績は落ちなかった。
```

```
ご飯食べるのはあとにしよう。おなかすいたけど。 
ご飯食べるのはあとにしよう。おなかすいたが。
```

By comparing these sentences, "けど" appears to be softer and more common in informal speaking. "が" delivers a sense that the speaker/writer is assertive, often used by a person in a higher position or in formal writing.

Answer (score 0):

I think that が is disjunctive while けど is concessive. That is to say that が may connect two disjunctive (disconnected) parts, while けど not just connects the two but introduces the succeeding clause as a circumstance that might be expected to preclude the action of the main clause but does not.

I think the term "disjunctive" is a superset of "concessive". That is to say that "disjunctive" includes "consessive".

Comment: I think I see what you mean, but can you give an example?

Comment: They both serve both purposes.