# けど and でも differences

Tags: word-choice

I realise that でも is only used at the start of a sentence whilst けど is only used to join 2 sentences. I have been chatting with lots of japanese and they always use けど to start a sentence after a fullstop.
Question is, is my understanding flawed? Or is it just bad habit to use けど

Comment: I think it's just colloquial usage of the word. In english we break grammar rules all the time as well. You're not *supposed* to use "but" or "and" in the beginning of the sentence, but we do anyways

Answer (score 3):

> けど is only used to join 2 sentences

けど is just a colloquial variant of けれども/けれど, and it can safely come at the beginning of a sentence. In monolingual dictionaries, it's categorized both as a 接続詞 (conjunction) and 接続助詞 (conjunctive particle), meaning it can be at the beginning of a sentence.

Comment: Thanks, so what's the difference between using けど and でも?
I read this but it seems to say that けど can be used to join sentences https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2738/%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82-demo-versus-%E3%81%91%E3%81%A9-kedo-to-mean-but